# React Native | useState Async-Await

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook, use-state

I have to update the state and use it in the function. It doesn't happen because I can't keep it waiting in the current system. It takes previous data and runs it. How can I hold it?

For example, the last value of the page is 1 when 3. Click is running and it should work as 1 in getReports, but 3 works. The next one is 1, but I need that instant.

```
const onClick = () => {
    setReports([]);
    setPage(1);
    getReports(); <- use page and reports list
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate and add as much information to the question as possible so an adequate answer can be given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution, get the previous value, increment it and update the state with this new value. In next line, pass same incremented value as argument to `getReports(new Value)`. Here we will be using states only for preserving the last number/index.

But if you want to go with only states then you shouldn't call the `getReports()` right away, instead you can use `useEffect` to listen changes to state and then call the method on change. Something like:

```
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getReports();
  }, [page]);

 const onClick = () => {
    setReports([]);

    setPage(1);

    // If page number is always incrementing
    setPage(page+1);
 }
```

Comment: my profile new :') points < 15 not vote. The moment I reach 15 points :D

Answer (score 0):

Setting state in React is asynchronous. This is because it re-renders the dom (or parts thereof), and any code after `setState` (or a hook) is called will continue to execute as normal. Forget async await as far as setting the state is concerned.

In your example, I should just pass the page number to the getReports function. As far as I can tell, there is no need to hold the number is state. Also, the call to `setReports([])` looks like it isn't needed either, as getReports should, I assume, overwrite it anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't use the page anyway, but since I use the reports list on flatlist, shouldn't it be in state?

Comment: Yes, store the list of reports in state by calling setReports(data) where data is the response from an api call, or from wherever you are getting your data. I assume the getReports() function needs to know which page you are on? If so, then pass it as a parameter rather that getting it from state. If I have misunderstood, you may need to clarify your question.